# Find the sum value: $\sum^{50}_{k=1} \frac{k}{1+k^2+k^4}$

Tags: solution-verification, summation

Find the sum value: $$\sum^{50}_{k=1} \frac{k}{1+k^2+k^4}$$

**Attempt:** = $$\sum^{50}_{k=1}\frac{k}{1+k^2+k^4+k^2-k^2}= \sum^{50}_{k=1} \frac{k}{(k^2+k+1)(k^2-k+1)} $$
Expanding into partial fractions, we have: $$ \frac{k}{(k^2+k+1)(k^2-k+1)}= \frac{A}{k^2-k+1} + \frac{B}{k^2+k+1}$$

$$k=A(k^2-k+1)+B(k^2+k+1)$$ $$0k^2+ k^1+0k^0=k(A+B)^2+(-A+B)k+(A+ B)$$
Comparing the coefficients, we have:

$$\begin{cases} A+B=0 \\ -A+B=1 \\ A+B=0\end{cases}$$
$A=\frac{-1}{2}$, $B=\frac{1}{2}$

So $$\frac{k}{(k^2+k+1)(k^2-k+1)}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{-1}{(k^2-k+1)}-\frac{1}{2(k^2+k+1)}$$
$$=- \frac{1}{2} \sum^{50}_{k=1}\left(\frac{k+1}{k^2+k+1}-\frac{k}{k^2-k+1}\right) - \frac{1}{2}\sum^{50}_{k=1}\left(\frac{-k}{k^2+k+1}-\frac{1-k}{k^2-k+1}\right)$$ $$ -\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{51}{50^2+51}-\frac{1}{1^2}\right)-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{-50}{50^2+51}-0\right)= \frac{1275}{2551}$$

I'm right?

Comment: You can see in Wolfram directely to check the numerical answer (cf. https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sum+from+k%3D1+to+50+of+k%2F%281%2Bk%5E2+%2Bk%5E4%29 ).Indeed, the answer is $\frac{1275}{2551}$.

Comment: Can you show your working for the partial fractions? I believe you did the partial fractions incorrectly, so even though you got the correct numerical answer (@A.P. ) , the solution is wrong / incomplete. $\quad$ IN fact, I don't understand the next line. How did you split up the terms? Looking at the coefficients $1/[2(k^2+k+1)]$, my naive read is that you're saying $-(k+1) -(-k) = (k+1)$. So please show much more working for a solution-veritication (esp if this is for school)

Comment: @CalvinLin See it

Comment: Thanks for showing your work. 1/ Can you explain how you got $k(A+B)^2$? There was no $A^2$ term previously. $\quad$ 2/ Can you explain the substitution in the next line? Where did $1-k$ in the numerator come from? $\quad$ 3/ How did you split the partial fractions further?

Comment: @CalvinLin I think I really made a mistake in the calculations, thanks for the help

Comment: The steps for partial fractions are good now. However, the next line of further splitting isn't immediately obvious, though I'm guessing you were treating it as $(k+1) -k$ in the numerator and further separating. That would explain how you arrived at the same answer as User's telescoping series.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You started correctly but made partial fraction wrongly

$$\sum^{50}_{k=1} \frac{k}{(k^2+k+1)(k^2-k+1)} = \frac{1}{2}\sum^{50}_{k=1} \frac{2k}{(k^2+k+1)(k^2-k+1)}$$

Now $2k$ in numerator can be written as $(k^2+k+1)-(k^2-k+1)$

and question will transform into telescoping series

$$\frac{1}{2}\sum^{50}_{k=1} \frac{(k^2+k+1)-(k^2-k+1)}{(k^2+k+1)(k^2-k+1)}$$

$$=\frac{1}{2}\sum^{50}_{k=1}\frac{1}{(k^2-k+1)}-\frac{1}{(k^2+k+1)}$$